# Google Maps Android API - Two Maps with getMapAsync()

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have two maps in one view fragment (see screenshot below), and although the maps run correctly and I can access one map via getMapAsync(), I am unable to understand how to run another getMapAsync() and distinguish it from the first.

Two maps together working well:

[image: Two Google Maps (Android) on One View Fragment]

A fairly simple View Layout (called "fragment_map.xml"):

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/map_card"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/miniMap"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In the Activity (or Fragment in my case):

```
    private MapView mv, miniMap;
    private GoogleMap gm;
    private View myLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mv = (MapView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mv.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        miniMap = (MapView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.miniMap);
        miniMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mv.getMapAsync(this);
        miniMap.getMapAsync(this);

        return myLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gm = map;
        gm.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        gm.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position.target));
            }
        });
    }
```

The maps inflate correctly and everything works smoothly, but as you can guess, whatever I do to "GoogleMap gm" happens to both maps due to

```
mv.getMapAsync(this);
miniMap.getMapAsync(this);
```

both pointing to a single

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
```

Any ideas as to how I can attach a separate GoogleMap to each MapView?

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Zeeshan Shabbir I used a boolean to first target the main map, then initialize the mini-map:

```
private GoogleMap gm;
private View myLayout;
private boolean miniMapReady = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    mv = (MapView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mv.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    miniMap = (MapView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.miniMap);
    miniMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mv.getMapAsync(this);

    return myLayout;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    if (!miniMapReady) {
        gm = map;
        gm.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        miniMap.getMapAsync(this);
        miniMapReady = true;
    } else {
        miniGm = map;
    }
    gm.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
            miniGm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(position.target, position.zoom - 5.0f, position.tilt, position.bearing)));
        }
    });
}
```

The ChangeCamera Listener here allows the mini-map to follow the user's interaction on the main map while remaining at a lower zoom level.

Comment: You can set a Boolean  for that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  I'm not seeing where that leads...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use boolean when `minimap` is ready set it to false. And in `onMapReady` check that boolean if it is true then do what you want for `mv` otherwise if boolean is false write logic for `minimap`

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'll definitely give it a try a little later today and let you know what happens.

Comment: This actually works really well.  I'll edit my answer and provide the new code.  Thanks!